# Where is DEBUG defined in the code?

Tags: c++

I looked at a sample code to create a log system on my server... And I found this

```
#if DEBUG
printf("something here");
#endif
```

I know what it does. It prtins something only if DEBUG has been defiend. But where is DEBUG defined? I looked at the all the header files but I could't find DEBUG..

Also, Could you please provide me a good example or tutorial about designing logging system?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: The second part has nothing to do with the first, belongs in a seperate question and has most likely already been asked / answered.

Comment: may be in `make` file or compile time flag `-DDEBUG` in g++

Comment: I do see -DDEBUG in make file and it's something like this CFLAGS:= -DDEBUG=1. What is -DDEBUG? Does it set DEBUG to 1? In other words, if I have something -DDEBUG2 =1 then does it set DEBUG2 to 1 as well? Thanks in advance..

Comment: `-DDEBUG` just sets the DEBUG macro to the "defined" state (but without a value), so it can be checked by `#ifdef DEBUG`

Comment: A macro that is set but not to an explicit value will have the value '1'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Compilers, at least those I know of, have an option to define preprossessor macros from "the outside" of compiled files.

For example, to define `DEBUG` with a microsoft compiler, you'd go with something like

```
cl -DDEBUG file.cpp ...
```

Comment: Exactly. That's the usual position to set the DEBUG macro. You don't want to change the source just to enable/disable debugging.

Answer (score 15):

Do not use the `DEBUG` macro it is not defined by C++ standard. C++ Standard defines `NDEBUG` (No DEBUG), which is used for the standard `assert` macro and your logging code would go hand in hand with it. `DEBUG` is compiler dependent. Therefore `NDEBUG` is ensured by standard to be properly set. Applying it to your example use:

```
#ifndef NDEBUG
printf("something here");
#endif
```

But my opinion is: you should not design a logging library around the `NDEBUG`/`DEBUG` pair. Logging lib should always be there, just to allow you trace the application's behavior without the need of code recompilation, which in turn involves new deployment of your code and possibility to postpone the bug prone behavior. The following DDJ article by Petru Marginean about design of logging libraries describes how to ensure that fact in a very efficient manner in C++:

Part 1: http://drdobbs.com/cpp/201804215

Part 2: http://drdobbs.com/cpp/221900468

Regarding the logging library take a look at the Boost Logging library at:

http://boost-log.sourceforge.net/libs/log/doc/html/index.html

---

I was downvoted because NDEBUG is said not to be set without explicit definition of it in the command line. I agree with that fact, but on the other hand  here I understand this question so, that compilation in debug mode, should also produce logging output. This fact is going to be better enforced when bundling the behavior to `NDEBUG` presence.

Comment: Downvoted because: (1) There's nothing wrong with using DEBUG here. (2) Neither C nor C++ sets NDEBUG. <assert.h> / <cassert> instead depend on NDEBUG being defined (or not defined) from the outside. (3) Because NDEBUG is specifically referenced by the standard to be coupled with assert(), it is best to use another name rather than NDEBUG for this kind of debug message. DEBUG is a very good candidate for that name.

Comment: I do not agree with you. The build process is usually organized so that NDEBUG properly works, otherwise the assertion macros are useless.

Answer (score 2):

Easy way to detect position of first definition, you add #define .

```
#include "someone.h"

#define DEBUG "dummy" // add this

#if DEBUG
printf("something here");
#endif
```

You'll get

```
foo.c:2:0: warning: "DEBUG" redefined
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
```

Or

```
foo.c:30:0: warning: "DEBUG" redefined
someone.h.c:2:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
```

Another answer, try to use ctags. run `ctasg -R` on the top of the project directory, run `vim /path/to/your/code.c`. move cursor to `DEBUG`, then type `CTRL-]`.

This way, you may find several definitions. You can find all with `:tselect` on the `DEBUG`.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio, you can set Preprocessor Symbols in Project Properties. As for logging system, take a look at [log4cpp](http://log4cpp.sourceforge.net/)